# Why is an error showing in my code for : Remove k duplicates in a string II #Leetcode 1209

Tags: c++, string, stack

In the question, for **input: deeedbbcccbdaa** and k=3 the **output: aa**. The explanation is that all 3 duplicates of every character are removed repeatedly. Since a has less than k=3 duplicates,and all the other characters have exactly 3 duplicates each, the final output is aa.
I have tried to solve the question as follows:

```
class Solution {
public:
string removeDuplicates(string s, int k) {
    stack<pair<char,int>> st; // to store elements with their counts
    string res; //final result string

    pair<char,int> t; //to access the top
    int n=s.size();
    st.push({s[0],1});
    for(char c: s){
        t=st.top();
        if (c!=t.first){
            st.push(make_pair(c,1));
        }
        else{
            t.second++;
        }
        if (t.second==k){

                st.pop();
            }



    }
    while(!st.empty()){
        res=res+st.top().first;
        st.pop();
    }
    reverse(res.begin(),res.end());
    return res;
}
```

};

It is not running and a memory error is being displayed.Please help me out with the solution.

Edit: 
the exact error shown is

```
Line 153: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0b6 for type 'std::pair<char, int>', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h)
0xbebebebebebec0b6: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_deque.h:162:16
```

I think there is something wrong in the step where I compare each element of the string with the character in the top of the stack. I have tried searching for other answers in google and stackoverflow too and made a few changes to debug it.Maybe there is some core issue I am not aware of.

Comment: "A memory error" is not informative. Can you please show us the *exact* error you're getting?

Comment: If you have the test case, you could just put your answer in your local compiler, run the example, and debug it.  You're asking us to do the job you really should be doing, which is debugging.

Comment: @tadman yes I am sorry for the inconvenience. I have edited and added the error message too. I hope it helps.

Comment: Why not `std::map<char, int>` to keep counts? I think you run the risk here of ripping everything off the stack, then calling `st.top()` blindly on an empty stack.